# What does "poorly hashed passwords" mean?

Tags: javascript, hash

I was watching an intervention called "How To Write Secure JavaScript Applications" (https://youtu.be/BeKMbTSm7x8) and it starts by talking about "poorly hashed passwords".

What does this mean? And how is that possible? I thought that hashing password means that it cannot be reversed (but can collide with another password according to the algorithm used).

Thank you in advance, and sorry if already asked.

Comment: Low-salt hash is bad for you.

Comment: "I thought that hashing password means that it cannot be reversed"  what if the hashing function is really bad/improperly designed/not used correctly/...?

Comment: It means bcrypt, scrypt, or argon2 are what you should use, and simple unsalted, uniterated hashes are poor choices. However, this is more a crypto question than a programming question and is off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you all. Where can I ask my question if it's the wrong section?